# DB Design : one or two tables to remember a user choice

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have a (huge) list of items in my database, my users (a lot too) are able to say if they like each item or not and i need to keep these informations in the database.

My question is what's the best design for that :

- one table with two boolean columns 'like' and 'dislike' for each item for each user (very huge)
- two tables, one for the users' like and one for the users' dislike (less huge tables, but will require to do additional joins)
- Maybe another way i didn't think about

Basically, in term of performance, is that better to have one very huge table (items * users) or to split it in two tables and using joins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by designing for functionality, and then tweak for performance. Do you have any query that needs to access both sets of information (e.g., calculating the "net likes" a topic is given)? If so, this would suggest a single table. Since a user cannot both like and disklike a topic, an improvement on your current suggestion could be a single boolean column - `true` can indicate "like" and `false` a "dislike". That way you can index it or even partition the table by it in order to improve performance.

Comment: I like that, that seems the most obvious way to do it, I should've think about it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Option #1, but wouldn't like and dislike be mutually exclusive?

In that case, why not a single table with item-id, user-id, is-liked.  If the user/item is in the table you know if the like/dislike is set.  If the user/item is not in the table, then it has not been set

Tables get big, but that's not really a problem if it's indexed properly.

Comment: I also need the information that users explicitly dislike an item, that means that they have seen it and don't want to see it anymore, so i need to know both information (one or the other for each) for items they already seen